# How to format JSON Response In Java Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, response

I have a Response Class with the set of private fields. Front end developers asked me to send the response of a service in this JSON format.
So far
Response should in JSON format and like this

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "message": {
    "code": "040",
    "description": "verified"
    },
  "qrContent": "aaa | bbb"

 }



        QrCodePaymentResponse response = new QrCodePaymentResponse();
         if (firstThree.equalsIgnoreCase(QRType.EZDYNAMIC.getDescription())) {
              axiPayQrCodePaymentService.ezCashDynamicQR(axiPayQrCodePayment,serviceContext);
              response.setStatus(RequestStatus.SUCCESS.getStatus());
              response.setMessage(----------------);
              response.setQrContent(returnValue.getQrContent);

    }
```

How to modify above code to send requested format?
Thanks.

Comment: show the model `QrCodePaymentResponse`

Comment: Sir its not the model its just a Dto whic includes  private String code;
private String description; private String qrContent; private String message; private String status;

Answer (score 1):

use the spring `RestController`. it's methods return the data as a JSON format

QrCodePaymentResponse.java

```
public class QrCodePaymentResponse{
    private String response;
    private String qrContent;
    private Message message; 

    //set getters and setters
}
```

Message.java

```
public class Message{
    private String code;
    private String description;

    //set getters and setters
}
```

AppController.java

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public QrCodePaymentResponse getPaymentResponse(){
        QrCodePaymentResponse response = new QrCodePaymentResponse();
        Message message = new Message();
        //set values to message
        if (firstThree.equalsIgnoreCase(QRType.EZDYNAMIC.getDescription())) {
            axiPayQrCodePaymentService.ezCashDynamicQR(axiPayQrCodePayment,serviceContext);
            response.setStatus(RequestStatus.SUCCESS.getStatus());
            response.setMessage(message);
            response.setQrContent(returnValue.getQrContent);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir,  I just asked how to set values which return the format of given response body?

Comment: @L.Anush set the values to the response object in a general way. RestController convert this response object to json format. please refer above edited answer

Comment: If i set values like that will it return in this format? "status": "SUCCESS",
  "message": {
    "code": "040",
    "description": "verified"
    },
  "qrContent": "aaa | bbb"

Comment: change it to @RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET , produces= "application/json")

Comment: @L.Anush please try with answer on yourself firstly. you can see it return the expected output with a jsp/ html page

Comment: @usman no need to set a `produces= "application/json"` with `@RestController`. it return the json object. but if you work with `@Controller`, set a `produces= "application/json"` for return the data as a json format

Comment: @L.Anush sorry for the mistake. please try with obove modified answer. :)

Comment: @Rathnayake .Bro ur a sri lankan neh?

Comment: @L.Anush yep bro. if the solution works, please accept the answer :-) Thanks!